# In NEURON simulator, how can I save the values of a graph to a file?

Tags: computational-modeling, software

In NEURON simulator, suppose I graph the value of a variable (i.e. soma.v(0.5)) over time. How do I save the values in the graph to a file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about the use of software. I reckon an answer to any question at this site should at least contain an element touching on CogSci.

Comment: Should probably be discussed on Meta, but software that is CogSci specific could reasonably be on-topic.

Comment: I picked CogSci because the software tag explicitly mentions the use of software: 

"Software": For questions regarding the **use** and selection of computer programs designated for instruction, **experimentation**, and data processing.

Comment: This meta post seems related: http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/471/are-questions-about-coding-psychology-and-cognitive-science-experiments-simulat

NEURON is used heavily in computational neuroscience to model individual neurons, and their networks. Cited over >1600 times: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=16673989093981586499&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not intuitive, but to save the value of a curve plotted in a graph:

1. Right click the graph window, and choose "Pick Vector"
2. Click on the desired curve (it should change color i.e. to red)
3. In the NEURON Main Menu > Vector > Save to File
4. Type in the file name > Save
5. File will have two columns, first one for X-axis values (i.e. time) and second for the Y-axis (i.e. voltage)